# How to add cronjobs inside docker container using docker compose version 3.3

Tags: cron, docker-compose

I have docker compose configured well but I need a daemon like job to update data automatically using some cron like background task. Does any one did the configuration of docker-compose.yaml file to create a cron job instance?

Comment: You can do it, but it is not a good practise. You should schedule the crontab job on the host. That job can start a container the updates the data and then exists. Or it can run a command in the existing container, updating the data you want.

Comment: I understood this but I've to do this (